# php cURL iis 6.0 windows server 2003

Tags: php, iis, curl

I am having an issue setting up cURL with IIS 6.0, Windows Server 2003, PHP 5.2.6

I have installed to `C:\PHP`

```
set PHPRC = C:\PHP\php.ini
```

copied `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` to `C:\PHP`

in php.ini, uncommented the line

```
extension=php_curl.dll

extension_dir="C:\PHP\ext"
```

`c:\php\ext` has the dll `php_curl.dll`

`C:\PHP` is in `PATH`

still getting

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely out of ideas then.  I don't have a lot of experience with IIS, so I don't know if it's some sort of configuration problem there or what.  Hope you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: ok, well thanks for ur suggestions. i'll post back if i ever solve this

Answer (score 3):

Make sure php_curl.dll is in the directory listed under "extension_dir" in php.ini.  If it is already, try restarting IIS (Apache always needs a restart from me when making php.ini changes).

EDIT 1:

Try opening up a command prompt to c:\php and running:

```
php -c . -i | find /i "curl"
```

Does it come back with any output?  If so, IIS is using the wrong php.ini file.

EDIT 2:

Is c:\php in your PATH?  You can check with "echo %PATH%" from the command prompt.

Comment: updated the post, i have extension_dir set and the dll is located there as well as in c:\php
this is drivin me bonkers...

Comment: no, there is no curl
and when i do a phpinfo() there is none either

it does say it's loading c:\php\php.ini, so am really confused why its not loading

Answer (score 2):

i ended up doin a reinstall of php, then unistalling php. then i copied and extracted the thread safe php package into c:\php rather than using the non thread safe package

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's loading c:\windows\php.ini?
I take it you've restarted IIS since you changed the config... :)

Comment: yes, restarted iis, as well as rebooted the machine.
i checked c:\windows\php.ini, though no file exists.
so i copied my c:\php\php.ini to c:\windows\php.ini, though still doesn't resolve the issue...
i'm tearing my hair out on this one...

Comment: Did you find any solution I am facing the same issue. I did everything right but still curl extension does not show up in phpinfo()